# How to execute clean task in dependent projects from a task?

Tags: sbt

How do I clean dependent projects in SBT from inside the code of a task?

I've checked before this related questions:

- [SBT: Traverse project dependency graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863209/sbt-traverse-project-dependency-graph)
- [get reference to "child" projects from "parent" in sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225905/get-reference-to-child-projects-from-parent-in-sbt)

but I'm getting a little lost with strange syntax.

I've tried this:

```
projectDependencies.value.foreach { p =>
  System.out.println(s"Cleaning ${p.name}")
  (clean.all(ScopeFilter(inProjects(new LocalProject(p.name))))).value
}
```

but SBT complains about dynamic scope:

> Illegal dynamic reference: p

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why don't you rely on sbt to know when to refresh the other dependent projects? What's the use case?

Comment: I'd like to automate creating a release artifact, and would like to clean also dependent projects, in order to guarantee everything is ok.  In Android contexts, I've had problems sometimes when not fully clean (ProGuard caches not updated, ...)

Comment: Why don't you do `clean` in the to-be-released project followed by the command you use to do the release?

Comment: I have a composite task that does clean and many other steps.  For me, the point is if the `clean` command does clean also the dependency projects?

Comment: Ah, right. It does not, only `aggregate`. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following in `build.sbt`:

```
val selectDeps = ScopeFilter(inDependencies(ThisProject))

clean in Compile := clean.all(selectDeps).value
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution offered by Jacek Laskowski (thanks), here is a more complete snippet:

```
val cleanDependencies = taskKey[Seq[Unit]]("Clean dependencies of current project")

lazy val MyProject = project.settings(Seq(
   cleanDependencies <<= clean.all(ScopeFilter(inDependencies(ThisProject))),
   package <<= package.dependsOn(clean, cleanDependencies)
): _*)
```